# Adding one value at the end of c++ array

Tags: c++, arrays, append, resize

I want to add one more value into C++ array, and I have this piece of code:

```
void print_array(int *array, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << array[i] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

void add_to_array(int *array, int size, int value)
{
    int *newArr = new int[size + 1];
    memcpy(newArr, array, size * sizeof(int));
    delete[] array;
    array = newArr;
    array[size + 1] = value;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int *array = new int[10];
    array[0] = 0;
    array[1] = 1;
    array[2] = 2;
    array[3] = 3;
    array[4] = 4;
    array[5] = 5;
    array[6] = 6;
    array[7] = 7;
    array[8] = 8;
    array[9] = 9;
    print_array(array, 10);
    add_to_array(array, 10, 11);
    print_array(array, 11);
}
```

I dont get any errors when I run it but the output is very wierd:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
0 0 -307888112 32767 4 5 6 7 8 9 1041
```

Any ideas how can I do it properly?

I know about vectors on lists in stl but i cannot use them so dont suggest it

Comment: Rather use a `std::vector<int> array(10);` and `push_back()` to add elements at the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function arguments of C++ are **copies** of what are passed and changing them won't affect what are passed. You should use references to have functions change what are passed.

Also note that now the new array has `size + 1` elements and the index of the last element is `size`, not `size + 1`.

Fixed code:

```
void add_to_array(int *&array, int size, int value) // add & to make "array" a reference
{
    int *newArr = new int[size + 1];
    memcpy(newArr, array, size * sizeof(int));
    delete[] array;
    array = newArr;
    array[size] = value;
}
```

Comment: It's better for sure but when im printing second time the value at 10th place is 0 and not the pessed value into the function. I can change it in main. How can repair this?

Comment: @F.Hand Fix the index for new element.